# Running Virtual Machine with 640x480 and 16-bit color depth

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu, vmware

To run a very old windows game in a virtual machine on ubuntu i have to run on windows xp with a resolution of 640x480 and 16-bit color depth. i can change that manually every time i start the vm but thats annoying. Furthermore i want to scale the window of the virtual machine to 1440x1080 (not 1920x1080 because of the aspect ratio) and every time i change the window size the resolution of the windows guest is changed.

I want to start the VM with the right resolution and the right color depth so that the os has no other change to increase the resolution. I could not find something for that in VirtualBox and VMWare Player. Is this possible with qemu?

Comment: In virtual box the graphical manager, dose not give all option. There *may** be others, through the command line.

Comment: Do, for VirtualBox, methods described in https://superuser.com/questions/443445/how-can-i-get-virtualbox-to-run-at-1366x768 help?